# Android content provider error

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I had an old content provider which is not exported and it should be as it is, since everything is based on that content provider. so I created an exported content provider which will access the old content provider for the data which could be exported.providing an abstraction between them.

but when running my application and using content provider from other app, i get an error message at Logcat

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.my.old.provider uri content://my.auth_url/ from pid=9876, uid=8976 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()
```

Is there any way out of this error. I can not do both since other content provider is best as it is and can not be edited

**Update**

```
    <provider
                android:name=".provider.externalaccess"
                android:authorities="some.authority"
                android:exported="@bool/bellowlollipop"
                android:label="myapp"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
     </provider>
```

Comment: post your exposed content providers manifest declaration. most likely you have used custom permission in your content provide and you have to grant same to your app.

Comment: @RahulTiwari updated.

Comment: you are not checking permission in xml. are you using it in java?

Comment: i dont care about permissions yet.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to query your provider ?